# How do I get SSL to work with Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, google-compute-engine

I have successfully pushed image to the Google Cloud Artifact Registry and have created a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance with it. I have set it up with http and https and am failing to call it with https. If I switch from https to http  it works as expected but is of course not as secure so I don't want to stick with it. It's set up with a static IP so that I can point my subdomain to it.

I have set up nginx on compute engine . so when I enter the domain name in browser with https it works and displays Welcome to nginx page. I used below docker run command to execute the app

```
docker run -d -p 8080:443 -p 8081:80  --name app <artifact registry url>
```

when I hit the URL with port 8080 it gives `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. But when I use port 8081 it works
Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Your question lacks details on how your container is listening for connections. HTTPS requires an SSL certificate and listeners configured for TLS. You mention Nginx which means you must setup SSL/TLS before building the container. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: You do not mention where Nginx is installed. In compute engine or inside the container. Note: typically port 8080 is HTTP and port 8443 is HTTPS. Definitely do not use port 8080 for HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, I have setup SSL. Nginx is installed on compute engine. Even if I use 8443 fir HTTPS its giving same CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Comment: Did you configure SSL/TLS inside the container? Why do you think you need to use TLS inside compute engine? If you want to connect to the container using TLS, you must configure the app inside the container to support TLS.

Comment: That depends on what is in the container.

Comment: @JohnHanley docker container contains asp .net core react app.  How to  configure SSL/TLS inside this container?

Comment: Read the .NET documentation. There are many tutorials by Microsoft and others. To answer requires the code you have written, how the container is configured, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask